# R - Including variables without merging

Tags: r

On how to include variables without using merge.

I am using the following code to sum dose in order to calculate total_dose.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(pid, medname, date) %>%
  summarize(op1 = sum(dose))

head(total_dose)
```

Also tried the following code.

```
df1$op1 <- df$dose
total_dose <- aggregate(op1 ~ pid + medname + date , data = df1, sum)
```

This gives an output of pid, medname, date, dose and op1.

I would like to include additional variables (var1, var2, var3) in the output df that are not involved in the group_by, so that I have an output of pid, medname, date, dose, op1, var1, var2, var3

Can I do this without using merge.

Based on the suggestions in the comments below.

```
total_dose <- df %>%
  group_by(pid, medname, date) %>%
  summarize(op1 = sum(dose))

new_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, split(total_dose, f = paste(df$pid, df$medname, df$date, df$var1, df$var2, df$var3))))

rownames(new_df) <- NULL
head(new_df, 10)
```

Would this work?

Comment: You need to aggregate them too then. For example in a group of (pid, medname, date) you get the sum of dose and what for V1? The first observation? The mean? Alternative (to keep all observations of V1, V2, V3) use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()`. See the difference of `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(new = sum(Petal.Width))` Vs `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(new = sum(Petal.Width))`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have used aggregate and summarise approaches as above to collapse the df to a single row per summed dose.  If I use the mutate approach I could keep the desired columns and use split to collapse the rows.

Comment: I have updated the question incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: I think at this point share a sample data along with your expected output

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for nested data, number of outer rows would match the number of unique groups while ungrouped data is still present and accessible.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# starwars dataset from dplyr as an example
starwars_heawyweight <- dplyr::starwars %>% 
  select(name:species) %>% 
  nest(.by = c(species, homeworld), .key = "details") %>% 
  # one way to access nested data, lapply or map would result
  # with a list and thus list-columns, with map_int & map_dbl we'll get 
  # vectors of specific types that fit better into our summary columns
  mutate(
    n = map_int(details, nrow),
    max_height = map_dbl(details, ~ max(.x$height)),
    max_mass = map_dbl(details, ~ max(.x$mass))) %>%
  # top 3 by max_mass  
  slice_max(max_mass, n = 3)

# grouped by species & homeworld, top 3 by max mass,
# 2 characters in Wookiee / Kashyyyk:
starwars_heawyweight
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   species homeworld details              n max_height max_mass
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <list>           <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Hutt    Nal Hutta <tibble [1 × 9]>     1        175     1358
#> 2 Kaleesh Kalee     <tibble [1 × 9]>     1        216      159
#> 3 Wookiee Kashyyyk  <tibble [2 × 9]>     2        234      136

# unnest all:
starwars_heawyweight %>% unnest(details)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 14
#>   species homeworld name            height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>            <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1 Hutt    Nal Hutta Jabba Desiliji…    175  1358 <NA>       green-tan… orange   
#> 2 Kaleesh Kalee     Grievous           216   159 none       brown, wh… green, y…
#> 3 Wookiee Kashyyyk  Chewbacca          228   112 brown      unknown    blue     
#> 4 Wookiee Kashyyyk  Tarfful            234   136 brown      brown      blue     
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, n <int>,
#> #   max_height <dbl>, max_mass <dbl>
```

`dplyr::starwars` overview:

```r
dplyr::starwars
#> # A tibble: 87 × 14
#>    name     height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender
#>    <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#>  1 Luke Sk…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu…
#>  2 C-3PO       167    75 <NA>       gold       yellow         112   none  mascu…
#>  3 R2-D2        96    32 <NA>       white, bl… red             33   none  mascu…
#>  4 Darth V…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu…
#>  5 Leia Or…    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema… femin…
#>  6 Owen La…    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu…
#>  7 Beru Wh…    165    75 brown      light      blue            47   fema… femin…
#>  8 R5-D4        97    32 <NA>       white, red red             NA   none  mascu…
#>  9 Biggs D…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu…
#> 10 Obi-Wan…    182    77 auburn, w… fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu…
#> # ℹ 77 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: homeworld <chr>, species <chr>, films <list>,
#> #   vehicles <list>, starships <list>
dplyr::starwars |> dplyr::glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 14
#> $ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia Or…
#> $ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150, 178, 165, 97, 183, 182, 188, 180, 2…
#> $ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0, 120.0, 75.0, 32.0, 84.0, 77.…
#> $ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey", "brown", N…
#> $ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light", "light", "…
#> $ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "blue",…
#> $ birth_year <dbl> 19.0, 112.0, 33.0, 41.9, 19.0, 52.0, 47.0, NA, 24.0, 57.0, …
#> $ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male", "female",…
#> $ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "femini…
#> $ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "Alderaan", "T…
#> $ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Huma…
#> $ films      <list> <"The Empire Strikes Back", "Revenge of the Sith", "Return…
#> $ vehicles   <list> <"Snowspeeder", "Imperial Speeder Bike">, <>, <>, <>, "Imp…
#> $ starships  <list> <"X-wing", "Imperial shuttle">, <>, <>, "TIE Advanced x1",…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>